# Find a python threads state (whether sleeping or active)

Tags: python, multithreading, sleep

I have a simple requirement, when an event occurs a thread is created and sleeps for x minutes before waking up to carry out its tasks and terminate.

But if another event occurs any thread that is sleeping should be terminated and a new thread should be spawned for the same purpose.

In python I believe the best way to make a thread sleep is,

```
import time
time.sleep(x*60)
```

Is there a way to learn the state of a thread (currently sleeping/idle or alive)?

Comment: A much more reliable approach is to periodically wake the thread up and check whether it should keep running by doing `for i in range(x * 60): time.sleep(1); check()`.

Comment: Threads and locks are very tricky. You might be able to use the standard Python module `sched` to do the work for you -- http://devdocs.io/python/library/sched

Comment: Any such information is stale by the time it is received.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using something like `time.sleep` you could set a variable to `False` and changed to `True` just after the thread "awake", for instance.

```
class MyThread(Thread):

    def __init__(self):
        self.awake = False

    def run(self):
        time.sleep(x*60)
        self.awake = True

    def is_sleeping(self):
        return not self.awake() and self.isAlive()  # You need to know also if you already started the thread
```

then you could:

```
if (some_thread.is_sleeping()):
    # more code here.
```

**Note:** As pointed out by Luke Wahlmeier, since you do `thread.start()` the thread is running. If hits a line as `time.sleep(10)` it still running, but now is counting to 10 secs. What this code does is check if the thread execution has reached some execution point (the line after the sleep in this case).

Comment: I tried this solution and it works. Thanks. Are there any caveats to be aware of with this approach?

Comment: @user2887201 No, it is ok. The method `isAlive` does something similar when the function `run` starts and ends.

Comment: Is it really work? There are two things with variables in compile languages (C/C++) - the variable can be put into register during code execution (languages like C++ has a volatile keyword to handle this aspect) and second, there is a need for memory synchronization within a thread (so there is a need to use memory fences, and to my knowledge it was out of scope of C++2003 even maybe in modern standards it hanled)

Answer (score 4):

There is really no way to do this well as a thread is either alive(running) or not.  Technically even if its sleeping it still running/alive its just not doing anything.

In general using sleeps in a thread is not really desirable as it can be a pain to adjust the time it sleeps and/or wake it when you need it to do something.

One thing I have used in the past for this is Condition in the threading module.  This allows you to put a thread to "sleep" by calling .wait().  You can then to an .acquire(false) to see if its blocked, and then .acquire() .notify() .release() to wake it up again if you need to.

Its a simple way to keep a thread around and from spinning or using come crazy sleep paradigm.

Another good option is just to have the thread consume in a while True from a blocking queue (Queue module in python) which will technically manage all that for you.

Comment: Welcome to the madness that is the 'multithreading' tag.  +1 for sane answer.  Please be aware that non-lame answers are pretty rare in here:)